# Python pip can't seem to find Python.h despite python-dev installed

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am currently trying to install getch, a simple python package and have run into quite a bit of difficulty. I recently installed pypy in a kind of messy way (I wanted to get numpy with pypy working, which was a considerable pain) so that might have to do with the problem I'm having.

Okay, so I try to run

```
sudo pip install getch
```

and I get the error...

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and as a bonus, a character encoding error.

This is the error that folks get when they don't have python-dev installed. However, I do. I attempted to work around this issue, by downloading the package and installing it manually.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

also gave me the gcc error from above. I have gcc installed, and x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc works in terminal fine. I made a simple hello world program in c that simply includes Python.h. That worked fine as well. After remove --purging pypy, python, and python-dev from my system, I re-installed just python and python-dev and I still have the same silly issue.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Here's a pastebin of the exact error I'm getting. pastebin.com/mjRdADZx

Comment: show the actual errors (from gcc). At the very least, show the line with Python.h

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mjRdADZx

Comment: [edit] your question and include the info from the pastebin. The log suggests (I'm not sure) that you are trying to  compile Python 3 extension as Python 2 extension. Download the tarball manually and try to install it: `pip install getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz`. Unrelated: use a virtualenv to contain your experiments -- if you break your system python installation; it might make the system unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually download the Python 2 version and install it. The version downloaded by pip is for Python 3.

The clue is this line:

```
Downloading/unpacking getch
  Downloading getch-1.0.tar.gz  # This is the Python 3 package
  Running setup.py egg_info for package getch

Installing collected packages: getch
  Running setup.py install for getch
    building 'getch' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c getchmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/getchmodule.o
    getchmodule.c: In function ‘getch_getche’:
    getchmodule.c:36:6: warning: unused variable ‘ok’ [-Wunused-variable]
    getchmodule.c: In function ‘getch_getch’:
    getchmodule.c:43:6: warning: unused variable ‘ok’ [-Wunused-variable]
    getchmodule.c: At top level:
    getchmodule.c:54:15: error: variable ‘getchmodule’ has initializer but incomplete type
    getchmodule.c:55:4: error: ‘PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

The Python 2 version is also 1.0, but the file name is `getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz`. You can download it [directly from the index](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/getch/getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz#md5=586ea0f1f16aa094ff6a30736ba03c50).

Once downloaded, extract the archive and then `python setup.py install` from within the extracted directory.

Comment: Is there any way to embed this requirement in a requirements.txt file so that it can be happily installed into a virtualenv at setup time? Is this a problem in the PyPi library that can be fixed? I'm surprised that pip would pull down a library for the wrong version of Python.